# How to edit my Excel dropdown list?

Tags: excel, excel-2003

How to edit my Excel dropdown list ?

I went to Data -> Validation -> Settings, and in that I found the values as =Attribute_Brands.

What I have to do to edit this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Attribute_Brands* is a named range.

On any worksheet (tab) press F5 and type *Attribute_Brands* into the reference box and click on the OK button.

This will take you to the named range.

The data in it can be updated by typing new values into the cells.

The named range can be altered via the 'Insert - Name - Define' menu.

Comment: i clicked OK ...nothing happens ... i went to define menu and selected the Attribute_Brands ... and clicked ..ok ..still nothings happens .... how to edit the list ???

Comment: The worksheet with the data may be hidden.  Use the menu 'Format- Sheet- Unhide' to unhide all hidden sheets and then try the instructions again.

Comment: Thanks ...it was hidden .. .THanks a ton!!

Answer (score 1):

Attribute_Brands is a named range that should contain your list items. Use the drop down to the left of the formula bar to jump to the named range, then edit it. If you add or remove items you will need to adjust the range the named range covers.

Comment: i used the dropdown of the left of the formula bar and selected "Attribute_Brands" but there is no changes i feel in the sheet. 

What is the expected change?

Comment: drop down to the left of the formula bar is not jumping to the named range

Answer (score 1):

The answers above will work for changing the *values*.

If you want to change the *number of cells* in your list (e.g. I have a list called 'revisions' which has 4 items, I now need 7 items) you will find that you can't simply select your list and amend it on the sheet, So:

go to your 'Formulas' tab

choose "Name Manager"

a pop up box will show what is available for editing. Your list should be in it. Select your list and edit the range.